# Give an example of a subset of $\mathbb {R}^2$ which is path connected but not locally connected.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, connectedness

Give an example of a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ which is path connected, but no point has a local base of connected sets.

Comment: Do you mean that no point has a local base of connected neighborhoods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$I\times\{0\} \cup 
\left(\{0\}\cup\left\{\frac1n\middle|\ n\in\Bbb N\right\}\right)\times I$$

If you want a space where no point has a local base of connected sets, consider the following

Let $U_{n,q}$ denote the line segment joining $(n+q,n)$ to 
$(n+q,n+1)$, and let $R_{n,q}$ denote the segment between $(n+1,n+q)$ and
$(n+2,n+q)$. Define $Z$ as the union 
$$Z=\bigcup \{R_{n,q}, U_{n,q}\mid n\in\Bbb Z,q\in\Bbb Q\cap I\}$$
This space is path-connected, but not locally connected at any point.

Comment: Does anyone know how to enlarge the delimiter " $|$ " in the set notation?

Comment: `\middle|`. It's worth noting that this is the so-called [comb space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comb_space).

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: The comb space is the standard counterexample-the really interesting question is-are there any other nonhomeomorphic examples?

Comment: @Mathemagician1234 My example is not homeomorphic to the comb space (for example comb space is compact). You can also take a cone on the rationals, or similar things.

Comment: excuse the statement was wrong!

Answer (score 1):

$$\{(x,y) \in I \times I| x \in \Bbb{Q}  \text{ or } y = 0\}$$

Comment: excuse the statement was wrong!

Answer (score -1):

$[\displaystyle\cup_{(\ \in [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q})\times 0)} (a(t-1)+p_1t; \ t \in (0,1), \ p_1=(0,1) \in \mathbb{R^2})] \bigcup [\displaystyle\cup_{(b \in 0 \times [0,1] \cap \mathbb{Q})} (b(t-1)+p_2t; \ t \in (0,1), \ p_2=(0,0) \in \mathbb{R^2})] $