# Path connected space that is not locally connected

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected

I am trying to construct a topological space that is path connected, but nowhere locally connected.

If we define $p = (0,1)\in\mathbb{R}^2$, and for all $q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$ $T_q = \{v\in\mathbb{R}^2\ |\ \exists t\in[0,1],\ v = (1-t)p + t(q,0)\}$, then 
$$
T = \bigcup\limits_{q\in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]}T_q
$$
the space of all lines connecting rationals in $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ to $p$, can be shown to be path connected but locally connected only at $p$. I thought of attempts to maybe generalize the idea to make the desired result. The immediate one of these attempts was to maybe 'rational duplicate' $p$ along the $y = 1$ line, i.e. to let $T$ be all the lines connecting every rational point on $[0,1]\times\{0\}$ to every rational point on $[0,1]\times\{1\}$, but the proof attempt did not go (I am not sure if this is correct).

Another idea was maybe a space-filling curve, but this seems a bit exotic.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Give an example of a subset of $\mathbb {R}^2$ which is path connected but not locally connected.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/499706/give-an-example-of-a-subset-of-mathbb-r2-which-is-path-connected-but-not-l)

Comment: I also found this: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/716738/find-a-subset-of-mathbbr2-that-is-path-connected-but-is-locally-connected?rq=1

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^2$, draw lines from $(0,0)$ to $(1,q)$ for all rational $q$ in $[0,1]$
and from $(1,0)$ to $(0,-q)$ for all rational $q$ in $[0,1].$  This subspace
is path connected and nowhere locally connected.

Comment: I think you mean from (0,1) to  (-q,0).

Comment: @DanielWainfleet.  No, I meant what I said.  However, you've brought to my attention an error which I have corrected.

Comment: Nice to see a very simple example

Comment: How should the set be written? I don't have a clear idea, I tried this $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb R^2: xt+(1-t)y\dots\}? $

Comment: Very nice ... love it!                  Reference @Isa 's question.  WilliamElliot 's description above is very clear, but to "code" it in a way that might seem more rigorous try: $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=mx, \text{for some } m \in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1] \text{ and some } x\in [0,1]\}$ union $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2:y=m(x-1), \text{for some } m \in\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1] \text{ and some } x\in [0,1]\}$

Comment: @SelrachDunbar oh ok, thank you.

Comment: im not  able  visualize the diagram?  pliz help me

Comment: It is two fans.  Plot some points a  draw enough lines to see it.