# Not locally connected but path connected particular example

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, path-connected, locally-connected

> Show an example of a path connected topological space that it's not locally connected.

**Example** (by [William Eliot](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/426203/william-elliot) in this post [Path connected space that is not locally connected](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2267036/path-connected-space-that-is-not-locally-connected?rq=1)):

In $\mathbb R^2$, draw lines from $(0,0)$ to $(1,q)$ for all rational $q$ in $[0,1]$
and from $(1,0)$ to $(0,-q)$ for all rational $q$ in $[0,1].$

This subspace  is path connected and nowhere locally connected.

My questions,

1. How to write in math notation the above example? I draw it and I think it has something to do with the lines

$$xt+(1-t)y, x\in[0,1]$$

2. To prove that it's path connected, the function that I should consider is $f(t)=tx+(1-t)y,t\in[0,1].$ Am I correct?
3. To prove that it's not locally connected should I use the definition? Can you give me a hint to prove this?

Comment: For 3, I would look at a neighborhood of (1,0).

Comment: Drawing a picture might be more illuminating than writing everything in terms of functions too.

Comment: That example is nowhere locally connected. An example that  is path-connected but not everywhere locally connected is $A\cup B \cup C\cup D$ where $A=\{0\}\times [-1,2]$ and $B=\{(x,\sin 1/x): 0<x\leq \pi\}$ and $C=\{\pi\}\times [0,2]\}$ and $D= [0,2]\times \{2\}. $

Comment: @DanielWainfleet But in any case,  the example work. Doesn't it?

Comment: Yes, it does, and it might have a name but I can't recall.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1.) This is already in math notation (words don't make it unmathematical). If you want you can write it as

$$ M:=\bigcup_{q\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [0,1]} \big(\{ (t, qt)\in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ t \in [0,1] \} \cup \{ (t, -q + qt) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ : \ t\in [0,1] \} \big).$$

2.) You can connect the points $(0,0)$ and $(1,0)$ via the path $t\mapsto (t,0)$. The points in the upper halfplane are connected to $(0,0)$ via the path $t\mapsto (t, qt)$ and the points in the lower halfplane are connected to $(1,0)$ via the path $(t, -q + qt)$.

3.) Recall the definition of locally connected space. A space is called locally connected, if for every element $x$ in this space and every open neighborhood $U$ there exists an open connected set $V$ such that $x\in V \subseteq U$.

Our space is not locally connected. For this pick $x=(1,1)$ intersect $M$ with with the upper halfplane. Let now $x\in V\subseteq M \cap(\mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R})$ be an open connected neighborhood of $(1,1)$. For $r>0$ denote by $B_r(x)$ the ball of radius $r$ centered at $x$. As $V$ is open, there exists $1>r>0$ such that $B_r(x) \cap M \subseteq V$.

Now we prove that $V$ is not connected. Choose $\alpha \in (1-r,1]$ irrational. Then $ V $ can be written as the disjoint union of

$$ V_1 := V\cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y > \alpha x\}  $$

and

$$ V_2=V\cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y < \alpha x\}. $$

This follows from the following observation:

$$ M \cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y = \alpha x\} = \{ (0,0) \} $$

(check this). Thus, we have because $V\subseteq \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R}$

$$ V \cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y = \alpha x\} = \emptyset $$

and hence

$$ V = V \cap (\mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R}) 
= (V \cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y > \alpha x\}) 
\cup (V \cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y < \alpha x\}) 
\cup (V \cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y = \alpha x\}) 
= (V \cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y > \alpha x\}) 
\cup (V \cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y < \alpha x\}) 
\cup \emptyset
= V_1 \cup V_2.$$

As $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y > \alpha x\} \cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y < \alpha x\} = \emptyset$, we have $V_1 \cap V_2 = \emptyset$. I.e. $V$ is the disjoint union of $V_1$ and $V_2$.

Note that $V_1,V_2$ are open as both $\{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y > \alpha x\}$ and $ \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y < \alpha x\} $ are open subsets of $\mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. As $B_r(x)\cap M \subseteq V$ we have

$$ x \in V_1, \qquad \left(\frac{1-r+\alpha}{2} ,1\right) \in V_2 $$
Thus, $V$ can be written as the disjoint union of two nonempty open sets and is therefore not connected.

Note that you can play the same game all the other points and thus, as pointed out by DanielWainfleet in the comments, our space is nowhere locally connected.

Comment: For 3.) It's because $\forall x,z\in\mathbb Q,\exists y\in\mathbb I,$ right?

Comment: @Ella I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Which part of 3.) is not clear? What do you mean by $\mathbb{I}$?

Comment: The creation of the line with irrational slope. $\mathbb I$ denotes the irrational numbers.

Comment: The point is that $M\cap \{(x, \alpha x ) \ : \ x \in \mathbb{R}\} = \{(0,0)\}$. But $(0,0)\notin M \cap (\mathbb{R}_{>0}\times \mathbb{R})$. Thus, the union of the two sets I wrote down really give $M \cap (\mathbb{R}_{>0}\times \mathbb{R})$.

Comment: what union do you refer to? I don't understand nothing

Comment: @Ella Sorry, I was way too sloppy. I hope now it is easier to understand.

Comment: @Ella Please let me know if there are still things that are not clear.

Comment: Yes, thank you.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven  +1   i  enjoyed  ur  answer by  reading    as  easy  to understand as   comapared    to other  like  Brian  M scot  and  william  eliot

Comment: @lomber Thank you very much.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven $ M \cap \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}_{>0} \times \mathbb{R} \ : \ y = \alpha x\} = \{ (0,0) \} $
im not  getting how $\{(0,0)\}$   comes ????  i think  it should be  empty.......can  u elaborate that ....??

Comment: @stupid Of course you are right. I should have written $(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}\times \mathbb{R}$. At the moment I do not have access  to a proper computer and therefore I prefer not to correct it right now. I will never find the right spot on my tiny mobile screen.

Comment: @SeverinSchraven,,okk  no problem,,  but pliz  edits  whenever  u have time,,. i will one more  read  ur answer

Comment: @stupid I edited it. In case you still have questions, don't hesitate to ask.